# Maven not running Spring Boot tests

Tags: java, spring, maven, unit-testing, junit

I have a rest Spring Boot REST API that I want to test. I can run the tests manually in Eclipse (without maven and by running the application as JUnit test) and it runs fine and displays the results, but `mvn test` does not "work" as you will find out below.

Here is my POM file:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>org.demo</groupId>
<artifactId>rest</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>UserRegistrationServices</name>
<description>RESTful API</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- To deploy to external servlet container -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- For Spring Boot testing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- For returning objects as JSON -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-xml-databind</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- To decode Base64 data -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.10</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This is the result of `mvn test`:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building UserRegistrationServices 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ rest ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ rest ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 9 source files to C:\Users\pmandayam\git\UserRegistrationServices\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ rest ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\pmandayam\git\UserRegistrationServices\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ rest ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\pmandayam\git\UserRegistrationServices\target\test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) @ rest ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.768 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-07-28T12:07:41-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 24M/212M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here is a segment of my TestController.java class in src/test/java:

```
@Test
    public void f_findByUsername() {
        // Finding user with username 'user1username'

        given().auth().basic("User1username", "Testpassword").when().get(
                "http://localhost:8080/users/get/ByUsername?username=User1username")
                .then().assertThat().body("username", is("User1username"));
    }
```

At the top of the TestController class I have these annotations:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
/* Tells the embedded Tomcat server to start on a random, open port */
@IntegrationTest("server.port:0")
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class TestController {....}
```

I'm not sure whats wrong. I don't have the surefire plugin but its looking for that it seems.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The code in the class you named `TestController` isn't a controller, it's a test, but the convention says that it's a controller (perhaps used in testing). By default, Surefire will be looking for tests matching `*Test`; rename the class to `ControllerTest`.

Comment: Important statement about the naming scheme for test-driven programming, indeed!

Comment: Works! I had same problem and after renaming to "...Test" Maven begins to execute my tests.

Answer (score 60):

Use the below maven jar. It fixed my issue.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This is necessary if you're using JUnit 4 with the latest Spring Boot version, see: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing#1-junit-4

Comment: You saved my day. This dependency is required for the latest spring boot applications.

Comment: this sollutions is work if you are using `org.junit.Test`

Comment: Mamma Mia! Wonder why my test coverage went to 0...

Answer (score 26):

try checking if you are using the correct package for @Test annotation. In Spring Boot 2.3.6 is `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`

Comment: +1.
Fixed by using this class in test method annotation:

Answer (score 17):

Even if this is not recommended (as not standard), you can configure the **maven surefire plugin** too, as follows:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*Test*.java</include>
            </includes>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Edit: Wildcard added before /Test*.java

Answer (score 13):

As this question populates first on search engines I thought it would be helpful for the people looking for the solution for the wired behavior of `SpringBoot` from version `2.4` onwards.

**Problem** - When you migrate your SpringBoot project from older version to newer like `2.5.x` then the existing `junit` test cases are ignored by `maven`.

**Reason** - SpringBoot has been migrated to `junit5` and thats why maven is ignoring `junit4` test cases. To see detailed test dependencies explore the pom for `spring-boot-starter-test`.

**Solution 1** - Either you write your test cases in `junit5` with class level annotation `@SpringBootTest` and follow `Junit5` rules.

**Solution 2** - Or you can use `junit-vintage` dependency in your project to run both `junit4` and `junit5` test cases together.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 6):

Another reason this may be happening is to have declared another surefire plugin in your pom. In my case I migrated an app to spring boot and left this in the pom.

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Test*.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>clean</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Spring boot test were executed after remove this part from the pom.

Answer (score 5):

If none of the above works for you and you are using junit 5 with appropriate annotations, issue might be with Maven Surefire and Failsafe plugins.
This is because of some conflict between the JUnit Surefire provider and the JUnit support in the Surefire 2.22.0 plugin release.
Update your POM to require the 2.22.0 releases of the Maven Surefire and Failsafe plugins.

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Refer [here](https://springframework.guru/why-your-junit-5-tests-are-not-running-under-maven/) for an example

Answer (score 0):

With Spring boot 2.5.0
junit-vintage-engine jar isn't added, hence any  org.junit.Test won't be run.

Only org.junit.jupiter.api.Test seems to run.

After Adding this jar (junit-vintage-engine) all my old tests(org.junit.Test) run absolutely fine.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can happen because your test class is not public.

Answer (score 0):

Adding org.junit.jupiter.api.Test  worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31521735)

Answer (score 0):

this works for my problem to update springboot 2.3.9 to 2.4.3

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this issue with spring boot 3, I had to upgrade my surefire plugin version to 3.0.0-M8

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M8</version>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

TestController - file name should end with Test.java

Comment: Already [answered by chrylis(https://stackoverflow.com/a/31681912/5730279) and accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I will add one more new answer here, basically you could import the wrong `@Test` annotation:

Good one:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
```

Bad one:

```
import org.junit.Test;
```

Answer (score -5):

For other people who still have the issue. Personally I resolved that by removing :

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

from the **pom.xml** file.